# Proof of arithmetic properties in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, arithmetic, proof-explanation

In general, in elementary numbers theory when we prove properties we begin with natural numbers then I was wondering how you can extend the proof to $\mathbb{Z}$ clearly and properly.

For instance, we take an assertion and we have to prove it for integers by using the Euclidean division. We know that for natural numbers we have $a=bq+r$ with $0\le r < b$ and $(q,r)$ is the unique couple of natural numbers which works. But in $\mathbb{Z}$ how do we proceed ? Do we have to consider four cases or can we just write $a=bq+r$ with $0 \le \vert r\vert <\vert b \vert$ (I suppose $r \in \mathbb{Z}$) ?

Thnaks in advance !

Comment: It depends on how it was proven that a = bq + r have unique solutions but there isn't any reason to assume a and q are positive.  If a = bq + r has unique solution q, r than a - b will have have unique solution ((q - 1), r).  We set up b to be positive in the posing of the question and we require r to be positive as a stipulation.  The statement itself has nothing to do with Natural numbers and will have integer solutions, non-neq int sol (q,r) for any *integer* a.

Comment: @fleablood If I proved the statement for natural numbers I did it for integers ?

Comment: I do not think it is of interest to deal with $b\le 0$. For $b\gt 0$, the sign of $a$ does not matter.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So we just have one case ?

Comment: That depends entirely on your proof. If I were to prove it I wouldn't make any stipulations of the signs of any of them.  The only stipulation is that 0<= r < b but that's arbitrary.  Any range of |b| will do.  0< r <= b for example.  Or 15 <= r < b + 15 or whatever.   But if you *did* make stipulations than you only did prove it for natural numbers. I personally, unless I'm doing induction or indexing, never prove or assume natural numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas well.... b can not equal 0.

Comment: How did you prove it.  If you proved it by induction for Naturals you can prove it for integers by showing if true for k than it is true for k $\pm$ 1 as well.  (Induction *down* as well as *up*.  *BUT* the induction step must work for down as well as up (i.e. holds true for zero and less.)

Comment: Well, it you really want to deal with $b\le 0$, we have more than one case. And when we generalize, say to Gaussian integers, there is no natural notion of positive. However, for the integers I would split into two cases for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok so for Bézout's identity what case is important ?

Comment: One can consider all cases important, though in applications $a$ and $b$ are non-negative. The usual proof works with no fuss, since it is easy to show that if $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$, there is a positive number of the form $ax+by$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok but if you took Lamé's theorem it seems to work only for natural numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you give, the way to extend it to $\Bbb Z$ is to allow $a,q$ to be positive, negative, or zero, but to keep the restrictions on $b,r$.

One of the reasons for this is that:

$b\Bbb Z = \{k \in \Bbb Z: \exists q \in \Bbb Z \text{ with } k = qb\}$

is the same as:

$(-b)\Bbb Z = \{k \in \Bbb Z: \exists q' \in \Bbb Z \text{ with } k = q'(-b)\}$.

That is, the positive multiples of $b$ are the negative multiples of $-b$, and the negative multiples of $b$ are the positive multiples of $-b$.

So when considering "multiples of $b$", we get the same set whether we use $b$ or $-b$, so we may as well use the positive $b$ to avoid as much "sign confusion" as possible.

It is a convention to measure remainders "counting up"; while this is by no means the ONLY way, it has the advantage of letting us determine the remainder of any $a$ (positive, negative, or zero) when divided by a positive $b$ unambiguously.

If $a \leq -b$, we will, of course, have a negative $q$.

Comment: Thanks, So for instance if I want to prove Bezout's identity, I just have to do it for natural numbers ?

Comment: Bezout's identity typically only holds in *rings*, which the natural numbers do not form. For example, to show there exist $r,s$ with $ra + sb = 1$ when $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, one of the $r,s$ is going to have to be negative, unless $a = b = 1$ (if $a \neq 1$ for example, then $a > 1$, and for $r,s,b  > 0$ we have $ra + sb \geq a + 0 > 1 + 0 = 1$).